# Streaming video from multiple cameras to html5 player

Tags: html5-video, h.264, red5, ogg, webm

Im trying to figure out a way of having a server which has a camera (or multiple cameras) connected via usb (firewire, whatever...) and then streams the video to users.

The idea so far is to have a red5 server which streams the camera feed as a H.264 stream and have a Html5 player like VideoJS with Flash fallback play the video. Looking at the browser support chart at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Browser_support i can see i would also need WebM and/or Ogg streams.

Any suggestions on how to do this? Is it possible to route the stream via some (preferable .NET) web application and recode the video on the fly? Although im guessing that would take some powerful hardware :) Is there another media server which supports all three formats?

Thank you for your ideas

Answer (score 1):

You can use an IceCast server. Convert the camera's output to Ogg via ffmpeg2theora and pipe it into IceCast via oggfwd. Then let HTML5 <video> play from the IceCast server. Worked for me for Firefox.

E.g.

# Tune DVB-T receiver into channel

(tzap -c channels-4.conf -r "TV Rijnmond" > /dev/null 2>&1 &)

# Convert DVB-T output into Ogg and pipe into IceCast

ffmpeg2theora --no-skeleton -f mpegts -a 0 -v 5 -x 320 -y 240 -o /dev/stdout /dev/dvb/adapter0/dvr0 2>/tmp/dvb-ffmpeg.txt |  oggfwd 127.0.0.1 8000 w8woord /cam3.ogg > /tmp/dvb-oggfwd.txt 2>&1